# How to printout a value in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a make file that I want to debug. I have a construct such as follow:

```
ifeq ($(CC_VER),4.3)
error "I am here"
AR             = ar6x qwe
CSL_LIBDIR     = $(CC_DIR)\lib
CSL_INCDIR     = $(CC_DIR)\include
else
    error "Please check that commands and include/lib path are correct for your version of CC  compiler"
endif
```

But it doesn't work. run this makefile from a batchfile which set the CC_Ver as follow:

```
set CC_VER= 4.3
```

I want to find a way to printout the CC_Ver so I can find why the if doesn't work.

Also how can I generate an error? The error "message" doesn't work.

I am using Gmake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$(error text...)` construct for the error. It generates a fatal error where the messsage is `text` as in:

```
$(error Please check that commands and include/lib path are correct for your version of CC  compiler)
```

Similarly, you can use the `$(info text...)` construct for informational purposes, as in

```
$(info CC_VER has the value "$(CC_VER)")
```

See [Functions That Control Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions) for the documentation.

If you are just looking to quickly inspect the value of a variable, you can also use the `-p` or `--print-data-base` option to `make`, which will print *all* rules and variable values.

The `if` statement fails because you have space between the `=` and `4.3` in the `set CC_VER` command. This space is preserved in your variable value, and consequently `$(CC_VER)` is not equal to `4.3`, but to `<space>4.3`